# Java doesn't know where to find .csv file, where should i put it?

Tags: java, csv, file-io, bufferedreader, opencsv

I have a csv file call v1.csv that is located in the main project directory. When I try to read the fuel, java never seems to find it. I have used opencsv and a scanner solution in order to read the file into a 2d array but both approaches do not work. How should I let java know where to find the file?

Scanner Solution:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "v1.csv"));
```

Opencsv Solution:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("v1.csv"));
```

Opencsv Alternate:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("/Users/yilun/Desktop/v1.csv"));
```

Stack Trace:

```
01-31 10:08:35.671: W/System.err(16946): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/yilun/Downloads/mapquest-android-sdk/samples: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-31 10:08:35.671: W/System.err(16946):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
01-31 10:08:35.671: W/System.err(16946):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
01-31 10:08:35.671: W/System.err(16946):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
01-31 10:08:35.671: W/System.err(16946):    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
01-31 10:08:35.671: W/System.err(16946):    at com.mapquest.android.samples.MyLocationMap.onCreate(MyLocationMap.java:73)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6084)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5158)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
01-31 10:08:35.681: W/System.err(16946):    ... 18 more
```

All do not work.

Comment: What's the exception / error message?

Comment: Learn about [class loaders](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077260/learn-java/learn-java-the-basics-of-java-class-loaders.html?null).

Comment: Depends where you are running from, try System.out.println(new File("v1.csv").getAbsolutePath()) to print out the full path of where it is looking

Comment: Error message is along the lines of, `File or directory not found`. It is a FileNotFoundException

Comment: @Prashant Isn't my third example an absolute path?

Comment: @ylun.ca It is, but windows needs the drive letter too. Try with`new FileReader("C:/Users/yilun/Desktop/v1.csv")`, replacing `C` with the correct letter

Comment: @BackSlash sorry, forgot to mention that I am on a mac. Is there a mac equivalent to the c drive?

Comment: @ylun.ca I don't know, it seems to be an absolute path then, `Users/yilun/Desktop` confused me, that's how windows organizes files so I tought you were on windows. Never mind! Can you please post the full stack trace then?

Answer (score 1):

In order to access a file in Java, it should either be located on the [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) or referenced with an [absolute path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/path.html#relative).